# Виджеты фреймворка

Tags: php

Пишу свою CMS (MVC). Мне нужно в левой колонке сайта вывести меню. Сказали, что нужно создать виджет меню. Вопрос: это должен быть класс или просто функция? Нужно ли создавать модель и вид?

Comment: Нужно создать контроллер и вид. Модель нужно создать при необходимости. Этот контроллер уже использовать там где нужно.

Comment: Виджет выглядит как класс? или там есть html-разметка и вставка кусков пхп-кода?

Comment: Виджет - это самостоятельная единица, которая имеет все необходимое, чтобы правильно работать (отобразиться). Таким образом его можно использовать где угодно в приложении. Если мы говорим на языке MVC у него должны быть как минимум 2 элемента: View (HTML раметка и РНР код) и Controller, который передает необходимые данные для View.

Comment: Если это ваш самописный фреймворк, то сами можете решать, как у вас выглядит виджет. Если нет, то стоило бы написать название.  
И вообще, начали бы знакомство с изучения готовых фреймворков.

Comment: Понятно! Спасибо!

Comment: Разделы для меню я буду тянуть из базы. Значит нужна и модель, верно?

Comment: Совершенно верно :)

Comment: Создаю в папке view шаблон menu. Потом там, где надо его вывести, инклюжу эту папку menu?))

Comment: Я не знаю как работает Ваш фреймворк, но есть несколько вариантов реализации вставки виджета. Либо непосредственно в нужном View вставляется контроллер этого виджета, который интерпретирует все в HTML, либо в нужном контроллере нужно интерпретировать этот виджет и во View вставить уже готовый HTML. Надеюсь понятно выразился